# Select / Clone parent of child class - append text to various attributes within parent and appendTo / insertAfter result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to, as the title says, select a parent div by providing the class of a child.

Then I need to take the entire contents of this parent and

1. append text the beginning of the "id" attribute of all  elements
2. append text the beginning of the "for" attribute of all  elements

And then I need to output this to another div by either insertAfter, or appendTo. I would prefer to just append it to an empty div which will have a class or ID.

So far I've got a bit of a mess:

```
$('a[class="on  maincatlink"]') // using this to select the parent
.parent() // parent is class="div2" but we cannot use "div2" as the selector
.clone($().find($ ("label").attr('for', +'helloworld')).find($("input").attr('id', +'helloworld')))
.insertAfter(".leftBoxContainer");
});
```

There's a few problems here, firstly this is applying the ID and FOR changes not to just the cloned content, but also to the original content that's being cloned. And secondly I'm not understanding how to append "helloworld" to the beginning of the ID or FOR attributes. The result here is ending up providing id="NaN" - well the code is just wrong there, if someone can please provide some pointers, thank you.

For a more simpler explanation without dabbing in my ugly code:

I need to select the parent of $('a[class="on  maincatlink"]') - append static text to the beginning of all the input ID's, append static text to the beginning of all the label FOR's and output the result in a div somewhere else on the page.

Edit:
// More Info on HTML

```
<div class="div2"><input checked="" class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid1" type="checkbox"><label class="maincatlabel" for="checkboxid1"></label><a href="http://127.0.0.1/zen11/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1" class="on  maincatlink">MOBILE PHONES</a>
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2"><input checked="" class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid2" type="checkbox"><label class="subcatlabel" for="checkboxid2"></label><a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor:default" class="on  subcatlink">APPLE</a></div>
<div class="div2"><input class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid6" type="checkbox"><label class="subcatlabel" for="checkboxid6"></label><a href="http://127.0.0.1/zen11/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1_6" class="off subcatlink">SAMSUNG</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

As in html here above, when a category or sub-category is active on, it uses the class "on maincatlink" and "on subcatlink". If the category is not active (being browsed by user) the class "off maincatlink/subcatlink" is applied.

The "on" class resonates throughout all prior categories that the current selected sub-category is a part of. I want select all these "on" categories and list them in another div. I want to retain the checkboxes and labels for purposes of retaining the tree menu that it creates.

Comment: For an extra bit of clarity, would you post the corresponding part of your html?

Comment: @BinaryCat Thanks for response, I've edited to include the html.

Comment: `+'helloworld'` remove the + (more answer coming I'm just typing)

Comment: Just to clarify, the main purpose would be to select the first instance of <div class="div2"> since this is the parent div of all the contents, and duplicate it. Also, adding a static prefix (i.e. "minimenu") to the input ID's and label FORs.

Comment: First you should know that `"on maincatlink"` is in fact two different classes, not one.  Second, your logic was almost in the right direction with this it just took a slight turn early on.  There's a quick way to do this but my noodles are boiling brb lol

Comment: @Deryck thanks. Initially the "+" was removed, but this simply makes all the IDs = "helloworld" which is undesired. I need to retain the current ID contents, and add a set prefix to all of them. Also yes, "on maincatlink" is two different classes, this was by design, to single out Main categories from sub-categories, so that they are never hidden when using the checkbox hack for this tree menu. But I think the fact that it's a double class would help provide the by-product that I need to achieve.

Comment: yeah sorry I skip-read a lot and just saw the `,+'` thing.  check answer and ill be back in a sec lemme know if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57952/discussion-between-deryck-and-user2255785).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    var cloned = $('.on.maincatlabel')
        .parent()
        .clone();
    cloned.find('label')
        .each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).attr({
            'id': 'prefix-' + $(element).attr('id'),
                'for': 'prefix-' + $(element).attr('for')
        });
    });
    cloned.appendTo('body');

    $(document).on('click', 'label.on', function (e) {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
    });
});
```

**Using HTML resembling:**

```
<div class="div2">
    <label class="maincatlabel on" for="checkboxid1" data-href="http://127.0.0.1/zen11/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1">
        <input checked="" class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid1" type="checkbox" />MOBILE PHONES</label>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <label class="subcatlabel on" for="checkboxid2">
                <input checked="" class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid2" type="checkbox" />APPLE</label>
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            <label class="off subcatlabel" for="checkboxid6" data-href="http://127.0.0.1/zen11/index.php?main_page=index&amp;cPath=1_6">
                <input class="catcheckbox" id="checkboxid6" type="checkbox" />SAMSUNG</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [See in actionish](http://jsfiddle.net/3A3YA/3/)

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'm going to use that to work the kinks out from my code and get the desired result hopefully :D

Comment: Likewise, I appreciate all the time and effort you took - excellent response from someone who's never even met me lol - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was the eventual code that works for me

```
jQuery(document).ready (function () {
    var cloned = $('a[class="on  maincatlink"]').parent().clone();

    cloned.find('label')
    .each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).attr({
        'for': 'prefix-' + $(element).attr('for')
        });
    });

    cloned.find('input')
    .each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).attr({
        'id': 'prefix-' + $(element).attr('id')
        });
    });


    cloned.appendTo('#navBreadCrumb');

});
```

All thanks to @Deryck for his guidance!

Edit: needed "index, " where appropriate.